# Disable Window Resizing Win32

Tags: c++, winapi, resize

how do I disable resizing by dragging the edge of windows?

Here is my window creation code

```
bool CreateGLWindow(char* title, int width, int height)
{
GLuint      PixelFormat;            // Holds The Results After Searching For A Match
WNDCLASS    wc;                     // Windows Class Structure
DWORD       dwExStyle;              // Window Extended Style
DWORD       dwStyle;                // Window Style
RECT        WindowRect;             // Grabs Rectangle Upper Left / Lower Right Values
WindowRect.left=(long)0;            // Set Left Value To 0
WindowRect.right=(long)width;       // Set Right Value To Requested Width
WindowRect.top=(long)0;             // Set Top Value To 0
WindowRect.bottom=(long)height;     // Set Bottom Value To Requested Height

hInstance           = GetModuleHandle(NULL);                // Grab An Instance For Our Window
wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;   // Redraw On Size, And Own DC For Window.
wc.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC) WndProc;                    // WndProc Handles Messages
wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;                                    // No Extra Window Data
wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;                                    // No Extra Window Data
wc.hInstance        = hInstance;                            // Set The Instance
wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);          // Load The Default Icon
wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);          // Load The Arrow Pointer
wc.hbrBackground    = NULL;                                 // No Background Required For GL
wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;                                 // We Don't Want A Menu
wc.lpszClassName    = "OpenGL";                             // Set The Class Name

if (!RegisterClass(&wc))                                    // Attempt To Register The Window Class
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"Failed To Register The Window Class.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                                           // Return FALSE
}

dwExStyle=WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;           // Window Extended Style
dwStyle=WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;                            // Windows Style

AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);     // Adjust Window To True Requested Size

// Create The Window
if (!(hWnd=CreateWindowEx(  dwExStyle,                          // Extended Style For The Window
                            "OpenGL",                           // Class Name
                            title,                              // Window Title
                            dwStyle |                           // Defined Window Style
                            WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |                   // Required Window Style
                            WS_CLIPCHILDREN,                    // Required Window Style
                            0, 0,                               // Window Position
                            WindowRect.right-WindowRect.left,   // Calculate Window Width
                            WindowRect.bottom-WindowRect.top,   // Calculate Window Height
                            NULL,                               // No Parent Window
                            NULL,                               // No Menu
                            hInstance,                          // Instance
                            NULL)))                             // Dont Pass Anything To WM_CREATE
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL,"Window Creation Error.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

static  PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=              // pfd Tells Windows How We Want Things To Be
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),              // Size Of This Pixel Format Descriptor
    1,                                          // Version Number
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW |                        // Format Must Support Window
    PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |                        // Format Must Support OpenGL
    PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,                           // Must Support Double Buffering
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,                              // Request An RGBA Format
    24,                                     // Select Our Color Depth
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,                           // Color Bits Ignored
    0,                                          // No Alpha Buffer
    0,                                          // Shift Bit Ignored
    0,                                          // No Accumulation Buffer
    0, 0, 0, 0,                                 // Accumulation Bits Ignored
    24,                                         // 24Bit Z-Buffer (Depth Buffer)  
    0,                                          // No Stencil Buffer
    0,                                          // No Auxiliary Buffer
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,                             // Main Drawing Layer
    0,                                          // Reserved
    0, 0, 0                                     // Layer Masks Ignored
};

if (!(hDC=GetDC(hWnd)))                         // Did We Get A Device Context?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Create A GL Device Context.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if (!(PixelFormat=ChoosePixelFormat(hDC,&pfd))) // Did Windows Find A Matching Pixel Format?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Find A Suitable PixelFormat.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if(!SetPixelFormat(hDC,PixelFormat,&pfd))       // Are We Able To Set The Pixel Format?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Set The PixelFormat.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if (!(hRC=wglCreateContext(hDC)))               // Are We Able To Get A Rendering Context?
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Create A GL Rendering Context.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC,hRC))                    // Try To Activate The Rendering Context
{
    KillGLWindow();                             // Reset The Display
    MessageBox(NULL,"Can't Activate The GL Rendering Context.","ERROR",MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    return false;                               // Return FALSE
}

ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);                       // Show The Window
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);                      // Slightly Higher Priority
SetFocus(hWnd);                                 // Sets Keyboard Focus To The Window
reshape(width, height);                 // Set Up Our Perspective GL Screen

init();

return true;                                    // Success
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style includes the `WS_THICKFRAME` style which, I think, is responsible for making your window resizeable.

Consider something like

```
dwStyle=(WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
```

Comment: However, `AdjustWindowRectEx` doesn't seem to work correctly if `WS_THICKFRAME` is not part of the style.

Comment: Not sure why is this one marked as an answer as it didn't work for me (Windows 10). The other answer worked like a charm though with the following line of code: `::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE)&~WS_SIZEBOX);`

Comment: @YePhIcK well, I gave this answer almost 7 years ago, tried it on NT 5.1 - 6.1 where it worked fine under consideration on how the question was asked by OP. Never tried it on newer versions and i'm not working on Windows ever since, so there is a good chance that some bits have changed meanwhile.

Comment: @YePhlck I am not certain the difference between this answer and what you suggested. All you seem to be doing is removing the sizing ability after you have created the window; rather than creating the window without that style in the first place.

Comment: works, when leaving out WS_MAXIMIZEBOX (win11)

Answer (score 30):

You can use WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ WS_THICKFRAME

The XOR will keep everything in WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW except for WS_THICKFRAME

Comment: This doesn't prevent maximizing.

Comment: @3Dave To prevent maximing AND window resizing, I used this code for the `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` style: `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_THICKFRAME` (Not the solution in this answer)

Answer (score 18):

You can try something like this:

```
::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE)&~WS_SIZEBOX);
```

It only disable resizing by dragging the edge of windows.
By the way, WS_SIZEBOX is the same as WS_THICKFRAME because of

```
#define WS_SIZEBOX WS_THICKFRAME
```

Answer (score 17):

If you use `WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU`, it disable both maximizing and resizing.

Answer (score 9):

Change your window style from WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW to, say, WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX. In other words, it's overlappedwindow minus the thickframe (resizable border) and the maxbox.

Answer (score 0):

Process the WM_SIZING message and override all attempts to change the window's rectangle.

Comment: But Windows attempts to resize, and it's look weird with resize cursor.

Answer (score 0):

For MFC,
Go to Properties > Border and set to "Dialog Frame"
It worked for me since the previous setting of the Border was set to "Resizing"

Comment: Looks like this post is about pure Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try removing `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` and replace with `WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_SYSMENUL`

Comment: That's what I meant

Answer (score -2):

That works for me, but instead of using

```
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW & ~WS_THICKFRAME
```

use only

```
WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
```

Comment: That doesn't disable resizing. To disable resizing, follow the answer by @thatsdisgusting. Use `WS_OPERLAPPEDWINDOW ^ WS_THICKFRAME`.

Comment: @DanielKvist Who is thatsdisgusting ?