# MFC - How to remove the resize icon

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to know if it is possible to remove the resizable icon in the bottom of the dialog in `MFC`.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to explain : [image]

The yellow section is the resize logo that I want to remove, but I want the dialog to still be able to be resized.

Thank you ! :)

Comment: This might be a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275989/disable-window-resizing-win32

Comment: Remove the `WS_SIZEBOX` (a.k.a. `WS_THICKFRAME`) from the dialog style.

Comment: Do you want to keep the dialog resizable, and just remove the visual feedback, or do you want the dialog to have a fixed size (which automatically prevents the gripper from being displayed)?

Comment: @dxiv I'll try that :)

Comment: @IInspectable I want it to be resizable, but without the visual feedback ! Thx :)